# How to calibrate cameras which are completely facing towards each other as in figure?

Tags: camera-calibration

I know how to calibrate a single camera and a stereo camera.

But I am not sure how to calibrate when two cameras are facing towards each other as in the below figure.

For my application, I am using two Intel Realsense cameras.

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It may be worth asking on here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try there